# Which permission is associated with variable_set()?

Tags: users, configuration

It seems that only site administrators can use `variable_set()`. If this is truly the case, is there a special permission that grants `variable_set()` function to site administrators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no permission associated to using `variable_set()`. Permissions are associated to pages, and not having a specific permission doesn't allow to see those pages; associated to part of the page, and not having a specific permission doesn't allow to see that specific part of the page; or associated to an action, and not having a specific permission doesn't allow to do/start that action.

There could be a module that checks the currently logged-in user has a permission before saving some data with `variable_set()`, but that doesn't mean every call to `variable_set()` needs the user to have a specific permission. [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7.x) doesn't even check for any user permission.

As for what done from Drupal core and its modules, none of the [functions calling `variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/calls/variable_set/7.x) that aren't part of tests use code similar to the following PHP pseudo-code.

```
if (user_access($permission)) {
  variable_set($key, $value);
}
```

This means that, for example, in a form submission handler for a setting page used by Drupal core, the settings will be saved independently from the user permissions the logged-in user has. That user has the permission to see that setting page, though.
If you are noticing that setting values for a form are saved just when the user is administrator, and that happens also for setting pages handled by Drupal core modules, then there is something wrong happening.

Comment: Thanks.. Do you mean that `variable_set()` is not restricted to administrator only?

Comment: It's is not restricted only to administrators. Eventually, it's the code using `variable_set()` that checks the permissions the logged-in user has, and that restricts its usage to administrators. As I said, that is not the normal case, though.

Comment: Thank you.. That clarifies the way Drupal works.. I thought about using `variable_set()` in order to set some global variable inside a webapp I am developing, I needed to make sure that it is safe to store the value using `variable_set()` without risking that a user would alter it later..